# How do you set an integer value with JSONObject in Java?

Tags: java, integer, put, json

How do you set the value for a key to an integer using JSONObject in Java?
I can set String values using `JSONObject.put(a,b);`
However, I am not able to figure out how to use `.put()` to set integer values. For example:
I want my jsonobject to look like this:
`{"age": 35}`
instead of
`{"age": "35"}`.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using ?

Comment: org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Cleaned up formatting so that all code objects are formatted as code.  Use proper spelling for Java (it starts with a capital letter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the integer as an int in the object using put, it is more so when you actually pull and decode the data that you would need to do some conversion.

So we create our JSONObject

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
```

Then we can add our int!

```
jsonObj.put("age",10);
```

Now to get it back as an integer we simply need to cast it as an int on decode.

```
int age = (int) jsonObj.get("age");
```

It isn't so much how the JSONObject is storing it but more so how you retrieve it.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but when I try to do that, I get a java error saying: "The method put(String,String) in the type Map<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"

Comment: Can you show your actual code by editing your answer and adding the code? Because it looks like you are trying to add it to a MAP which you have declared to have the types of string and string,

Comment: Avoid using cast, because org.json library already have a `getInt("key")` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using org.json library, you just have to do this:

```
JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject();
myJsonObject.put("myKey", 1);
myJsonObject.put("myOtherKey", new Integer(2));
myJsonObject.put("myAutoCastKey", new Integer(3));

int myValue = myJsonObject.getInt("myKey");
Integer myOtherValue = myJsonObject.get("myOtherKey");
int myAutoCastValue = myJsonObject.get("myAutoCastKey");
```

Remember that you have others "get" methods, like:

```
myJsonObject.getDouble("key");
myJsonObject.getLong("key");
myJsonObject.getBigDecimal("key");
```